# Memory leak? memory_get_usage() vs actual process memory

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with a possible memory leak in my console PHP application. It is created with the Laravel framework, using artisan. Running PHP 5.6.2. It's a huge loop that will gather data from a webservice and insert it into my own database, probably around 300k rows.

For each loop I print out memory usage in the console. The weird thing is that memory_get_usage() and memory_get_usage(true) reports that it uses roughly 13MB memory. But the php process keeps using more and more memory. If I let it run for a few hours it uses almost 1GB memory, and the loop keeps going slower and slower.

It will not terminate due to the PHP memory limit, even if it passes it by far.

I am trying to figure out why this happens and how this actually works. As I understand it, memory_get_usage reports the memory used by MY script, what I have written. So unsetting variables, cleaning up etc. should not be the problem, right? I also try to force garbage collection  every ~300 entries with no luck.

Do anyone have some general tips on how I can troubleshoot this? And maybe explain why the memory used by the process is shown by the memory_get_usage function :-)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your php version? Any specific extensions?

Comment: Some code would be useful. Difficult to give a specific answer when the question is so broad and generic

Comment: Edited my entry now with PHP version, which is 5.6.2. No specific extensions. The code is pretty humongous, and I don't know if this is bad courtesy around here, but I would really like to learn how to troubleshoot this problem, rather then someone doing it for me. I have read about using xcode for profiling my code, but didn't really figure out how. Any tips for pointing me in the right directions is appreciated :)